# How can a Knockout snippet display in a data-badge?

Tags: magento-2.1, knockoutjs

Attempting to display the current total of products in the mini-cart in a data-badge.  The Knockout text displays in this version:

```
<span class="counter-number" data-badge="">My Cart<!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
```

But when trying to display it in the data-badge attribute like this:

```
<span class="counter-number" data-badge="<!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->">My Cart</span>
```

Instead of rendering a number for the items in the cart it outputs the KO text as a literal string.

Comment: I run a 'grep' command on Magento 2 source on word 'badge'. I did not see meaningful occurrences of it.

Answer (score 0):

**There are no data-badge attribute is available in knockout js.**

You have to use `data-bind` to get knockout variable value.

You have to try with below way,

```
<span class="counter-number">My Cart<!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
```

OR

```
<span class="counter-number" data-bind="text: getCartParam('summary_count')">My Cart</span>
```

Comment: It does not look like either of these achieve the end goal of getting the KO output into the data-badge attribute.